# Merge the changes onto a branch but not take the changes from the target branch

Tags: git, github, git-bash

So I am following micro service architecture and using one GitHub repo to maintain the code. Now I have a backend branch which is the starting point for any micro service that I create. I have a userserv branch and a authserv branch, But it becomes difficult to manage the code when there are dependencies between the micro services. so I need to have a test branch onto which I can put the code of each micro service and when I check out that test branch, I see all the folders for all the micro services that are merged onto that, but what I dont want is that when I merge a new micro service to that test branch, I should not get the code from other micro services (that are already merged to the test branch) in the new micro service branch. Is there a way to achieve that?

[image: This diagram can explain it better]

Comment: You want to freeze some specific parts of your codebase from receiving update but at the same time take update from some other specific part like your micro-service directory.

Comment: @VishwanathI have updated the question and added a picture. I dont want the authserv code to come on userserv or vice versa after merge

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood : you are using branches as directories, and try to implement dependency rules such as "the core module should not depend on the authserv module" by splitting code through *branches*.

If this is the case : you should rather put all your code in the same branch, in separated directories, and check your code segregation rules with other means :

- coding guidelines
- build scripts that make sure that building `userserv` does not use `authserv`'s code, and vice versa
- ...